# \n not working in google apps script Browser.msgBox

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying the following to add line breaks to a message box but it is not working.

```
function showMsgBox(){
  var msg = 'name: \n \n \n Doc URL';
  Browser.msgBox("Selected Doc template:", msg, Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
```

I does not matter single or double quotes.

I also tried `Browser.msgBox(msg);` but it is all the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to double-escape "\n" for historical reasons

```
function myFunction() {
  Browser.msgBox("Hello\\nWorld")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that we need to escape '\' in msgBox

Comment: But why is it like this? Is it something like "Browser.msgBox is actually another script interpreter"?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right. msgBox do not respect extra whitespace or newline. A [similar issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1608) has been raised in Issue Tracker. You may star it and provide your feedback there.

[Issue 1608:    Add an option to Browser.msgBox() to respect whitespace](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1608)