# Google apps script, getBody() from Gmail, regex \n

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Good evening. 
Have such problem with regex new-line character ("\n") in Google app script. I'm using .getbody() method for mail parse and get some of this

```
<td valign="middle" width="43" align="left">
<img src="http://img/mail-new-oct/icon2.png" style="display: block; vertical-align: middle;" alt="Logo">
</td>
<td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family: 'Open Sans',  Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 30px; color: #000000; font-weight: 400; text-align: left;">0972398182
</td>
```

For this part, i need phone number 0972398182. 
I try get it with this expression:

```
icon2.*\n.*\n.*>\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*(?=<\/td>)
```

icon2 - is one unique identification for this html body, so i need to use it. 
 Go through without ("\n") impossible in this way, and finally it doesn't work. I read, that GAS doesn't work with ("\n") , but maybe have other way how to solve this? 
 Will be grateful for any help, thanks!

Comment: Use `\v` to match newlines. Like `icon2.*\v.*\v.*>\s*(.+?)\s*\v*\s*(?=<\/td>)`

Comment: Tried, same result :(

Comment: Even if you use `\v+` instead of `\v`?

Comment: Also tried, nothing going on. I found same question with your comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771381/eliminate-newlines-in-google-app-script-using-regex maybe try use .replaceText("\\v+", "") to del all new lines in `getBody()` html text? But i dont know how to do this. Tried add it in line `content = message[j].getBody()` shows eror

Comment: Hot to replace \n in getBody() HTML ?

Comment: If you can provide a simple, minimal code to repro the issue, I could check.

Comment: I can send you test message on email which i try to parse + sample code. Dont know another way how to test html body from Gmail

Comment: Wait, did you try accessing `.getBody().getText()`?

Comment: You may actually use `\n` but not for all kinds of linebreaks, only those you copy/paste. When you press CTRL+ENTER, the linebreak can be detected with `[\r\n]+`.

Comment: Tried .getbody().gettext(). TypeError: Cannot find function gettext()

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, Man!!! You'r great !!! This freaky [\r\n]+  at last works !!! Do it like `icon2.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*left.*>\s*(.+?)\s*(?=<\/td>)` thank you again, you filled my evening with joy

Comment: Good, let me post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a combination of newlines and carriage returns in your input string. That means you may use `[\r\n]+` character class with `+` quantifier:

```
icon2.*[\r\n]+.*[\r\n]+.*left.*>\s*(.+?)\s*(?=<\/td>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the given workaround in [Issue #13](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=13) logged in google-apps-script-issues tracker. Use:

> **`\\n`**.

In addition to that, you may want to also check solutions given in the following posts:

- [\n not working in google apps script Browser.msgBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804502/n-not-working-in-google-apps-script-browser-msgbox)
- [How to add line breaks in a cell before specific keywords in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76035/how-to-add-line-breaks-in-a-cell-before-specific-keywords-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Thanks, dont know about double slash. Tried this variant, but still dont work. Probably its work in case with method msgBox() where no html code