# Matching paragraph breaks with replaceText() in a Google Apps Script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

Replacing a *paragraph break* with something else in a Google Doc can be done via the "Find and Replace..." dialog box, using `\n` as a search pattern, with regular expressions enabled.

The same pattern, however, does not work in a Google Apps Script:

```
body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
// note that escaping the backslash is required
body.replaceText("\\n", "EOL"); //matches nothing
```

even though:

```
body.replaceText("\\v", "EOL"); //matches "soft returns"
body.replaceText("\\s", "EOL"); //matches whitespace
```

The [official reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#replacetextsearchpattern-replacement) is very terse, other than warning of the need to escape the backslashes.

It is obviously possible to solve the problem programmatically (see for example [my own answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962369/how-to-find-and-remove-blank-paragraphs-in-a-google-document-with-google-apps-sc)), but does anyone know how to write a regular expression pattern that can be used as an argument in `replaceText()` and that matches a paragraph break?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771381/eliminate-newlines-in-google-app-script-using-regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556574/google-apps-script-getbody-from-gmail-regex-n Are you getting any actual errors? Or simply, nothing is replaced? Please detail the escaping patterns you have tried

Comment: Does a simple "Find" (as in Find and Replace menu using regex option) for `\n` mark the correct positions?

Comment: @I'-'I yes, a simple Find-and-Replace with RegEx enabled WILL match `\n`. Which makes the script's apparent limitation even more frustrating

Comment: @tehhowch, nothing is *matched*. Just for the heck of it, I have tried patterns containing from 1 all the way to 4 backslashes, as in `"\\\\n"`

Comment: @bro, I have changed the title and rephrased much of the question, hope it's better now.